# Onclick exactly on button text not applying :active css

Tags: html, css

This is more of an extremely niche issue, but I'll explain as best as I can.

I have a button that looks like so

```
  <button id="button-stop" class="button fault" style="float:right;" (mouseup)="clickStop()">stop</button>
```

With CSS that looks like so

```
button:active {
  border-style: inset;
  border-width: 5px;
}
```

Now this looks fine on all browsers across the board. However I have a requirement to use an embedded browser with a touch screen that isn't giving me any feedback on what is going on. The CSS will apply whenever the user touches around the button, but if they directly touch the "STOP" text the `border-style:inset;` does not apply, but the JS will still go through oddly enough.

I am at a lost of ways to attempt to fix this issue, maybe it's an `innerHtml` vs `innerText` issue?

Comment: Have you tried using touch events? Also could you make an example on Plunker or something like it? I am a little bit confused about how do you know the JS is function is actually being executed.

Comment: This is more of a CSS issue than a JS issue. Sadly there is no :touch class. the clickStop() actives it's code when the css effect doesn't get applied.